# Definition of a convex set, attempt to extend it to convex sets of functions

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Given this definition:

a set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is convex if $\mathbf{x}^1$, $\mathbf{x}^2 \in S$ implies that $\beta \mathbf{x}^1 + (1-\beta)\mathbf{x}^2 \in S$ for all $0 \le \beta \le 1$

and since $C^1(\mathbb{R}_{>0}) \subset C^1$ can I say, making a naive extension of the definition, that the set of $C^1$ functions defined in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is convex?

Comment: Any vector space is a convex set..

Comment: The definition works in any vector space.